# How to do line break in Responsibilities field of Developer story?

Tags: support, developer-story

How to do line break or `<ol>` tag in Responsibilities field of Developer story?

I fill the textbox like

[image]

However, the EOL disappear after I save the article.
[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried the standard Markdown syntax, supported across Stack Exchange?

Comment: That worked! silly me!